# skip the sink step in kafka when posted data corrupted

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-kafka, avro, flume

**At the java server side** after some processes, I am posting the log data (json format) from server to kafka via restful webservice.

**At the hdfs side** my sink type is avro. So for parsing json (source) to avro (destination) I am using morphline and avro schema.

If the posted data is not suitable for morphline or avro schema, normally I get the error below,

> Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Illegal
>   unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code 10)): has to be escaped using
>   backslash to be included in string value

Also if I get this once, offset is not move anymore. Briefly if kafka gets this error only once, it can't sink posted data anymore.

To avoid from this error, I suppose that there is 2 solutions. First one is that at the server side writing json validator for avro schema which used in big data side. Second way which I prefered is that skip and do not sink the log data which unformatted for requested avro schema. But after skip a corrupted data, if kafka gets suitable data it should sink it.

I think it can be possible if I add some parameters in flume or kafka configuration file. So how can I skip the sink step when posted data is not suitable for the requested schema or requested morphline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem at morphline side,

Added try-catch code block in morphline like that

```
morphlines: [
  {
    id: convertJsonToAvro
    importCommands: [ "org.kitesdk.**" ]
    commands: [
       {
         tryRules {
              catchExceptions : true
           rules : [
             {
               commands : [
                 # save initial state
                 { readJson {} }
                # extract JSON objects into fields
              { extractJsonPaths {
                flatten: true
                paths: {
            PROJECT_NAME: /PROJECT_NAME
            WSDL_NAME: /WSDL_NAME
            ....
            ....
            ....
            MESSAGE_OUT: /MESSAGE_OUT
        }
      } }
      # convert the extracted fields to an avro object
      # described by the schema in this field
      { toAvro {
        schemaFile:/u0x/myPath/myAvroSchema.avsc
      } }
      # serialize the object as avro
      { writeAvroToByteArray: {
        format: containerlessBinary
              } }
           ]
         }
         {
          commands : [
            { logWarn { format : "Ignoring record with unsupported input format in myLogService: {}", args : ["@{}"] } }
            { dropRecord {} }    
            ]
         }
       ]
     }   
    }    
   ]
  }
]
```

In `tryRules` I am forcing the code to catch all exceptions.

In `rules:` You can write `"command:"` block whatever you want, if one of them throws an exception except the last command block, the last command will run. Remember that last one is "catch". I mean my in case, if first command block fails, last (second) command will run. If first command run perfectly, last command won't work, because last command block work like a catch block.

So when the code  `readJson {}` fails in first command block, it throw an exception and last command (catch block) handles it so it don't try sink current data in kafka topic because it will run `dropRecord {}`.

For detailed documentation, you can visit [kitesdk](http://kitesdk.org/docs/current/morphlines/morphlines-reference-guide.html#/tryRules).